# how to define an array of a particular enum case in swift

Tags: swift, enums

I want to define an enum case which is recursively defined by a particular instance of the same enum

```
enum Menu {
  case item(String)
  case submenu([.item]) // i want a submenu to be defined by an array of items
}
```

the `submenu` case isn't correct:

`case submenu([.item])`

how can I confine it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All cases of an `enum` are of the same `enum` type, so you cannot declare an `Array` that can only hold a specific case of an enum.

However, you can achieve your goals by creating 2 enums instead of one and making the `Menu.submenu` enum case take the other enum as its associated value.

```
enum Menu {
    case item(MenuItem)
    case submenu([MenuItem])
}

enum MenuItem {
  case item(String)
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
let menu = Menu.item(.item("main"))
let submenu = Menu.submenu([.item("a"), .item("b")])
```

Comment: I'll define 2 enums like you are suggesting