# Can a function argument's type be a specific enum 'case'?

Tags: swift, enums

Assuming we have an `enum` with associated values:

```
enum MyTimer {
    case describe(userId: String, 
                  endTime: Int)
    case vote(endTime: Int)
}
```

Can we define a function with a specific case of this `enum` as argument type, like:

```
func onDescribeTimerChange(timer: MyTimer.describe) {
    print(timer.userId)
}
```

This is the syntax I would use with a Kotlin `sealed class` because it makes it clear which case of the enum the function is designed for. But currently the Swift compiler rejects it with the message:

> Enum case 'Describe' is not a member type of 'MyTimer'

Comment: Cases are not types, so no. (also, it's convention to use camelCase for non-type identifiers, like cases).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @NewDev. Good point about camelCasing, I'll change it in the question so it looks cleaner 

Comment: Enumeration cases with associated types do *feel* like types in their own right, so I can see where you're coming from. But if you're tempted to *use* one as a type, that's probably an indication that you should use class inheritance rather than enumerations, e.g. `class Timer` and `class DescribeTimer : Timer`, etc. That will let you use `DescribeTimer` as a type.

Comment: @Caleb, using class inheritance is a great suggestion! I hadn't thought about it  Actually, it's what makes it work when using Kotlin's `sealed class`

Comment: [Duplicate] I don't think this question should be closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65073559/4084269, because it describes a completely different use case and can be useful to people encountering the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass an Enum as a parameter, not its cases. So you can either write that function like this -

```
enum MyTimer {
    case describe(userId: String,
                  endTime: Int)
    case vote(endTime: Int)
}


func onDescribeTimerChange(timer: MyTimer) {
    switch timer {
    case let .describe(userId, endTime):
        print(userId, endTime)
    case .vote(let endTime):
        print(endTime)
    }
}


onDescribeTimerChange(timer: .describe(userId: "userID", endTime: 2))
```

Or you can use that as a method associated with your MyTimer enum type, like this -

```
enum MyTimer {
    case describe(userId: String,
                  endTime: Int)
    case vote(endTime: Int)
    
    func onDescribeTimerChange() {
        switch self {
        case let .describe(userId, endTime):
            print(userId, endTime)
        case .vote(let endTime):
            print(endTime)
        }
    }
}


MyTimer.describe(userId: "userID", endTime: 1).onDescribeTimerChange()
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing alternative implementations @VincentJoy. Also I learnt from your code snippets that we can use `case let .describe(userId, endTime)` as a slightly more concise version of `case .describe(let userId, let endTime)` 

Comment: @Josselin the second option is meant to be used when one of the associated values might not be constant `.describe(let userId, var endTime)`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific answer is no, as said by New Dev in their comment.

Note that `Timer` is a Foundation class, and you should avoid using that as an enum name.

Comment: I see. Good point about `Timer` being a Foundation class 